# When I use cross thread then my application doesn't respond until background operations complete

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm working on windows from application in .net framework 2.0.

There is some operations run in background like database backup, progress bar and label text update etc.
But When I use cross thread then my application doesn't respond(busy icon) until background operations complete

This is example code

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(UpdateInfo));
            t.Start();
        }


        private void UpdateInfo()
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(UpdateInfo)); 
            }
            else
            { 
                // send query to database here for taking backup that could take time
                // update progress bar
                //I'm also using sqlconnection InfoMessage here

                label1.Text = "Text upading......
            }
        }
         private void OnInfoMessage(sender As Object, e As SqlInfoMessageEventArgs)
         {
         }
```

**Scenario:**
Scenario is user could cancel operation but it can't due to application not responding

================Update Code==========================================

My Code is like

```
private void btnBackup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MyThreadFunc));
  t.Start();
}


public void MyThreadFunc()
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired) {

        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(Backup));
    } else {
        Backup();
    }
}

public void Backup()
{
    string databaseName = cbDatabase.Text;// getting the name of database for backup


    SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog(); // dialog will open   
    string backupFileName = SaveFileDialog1.FileName; // getting location of backup


    //============ database query==================

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
    con.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = true;
    con.InfoMessage += OnInfoMessage;

    con.Open();

    query = string.Format("backup database {0} to disk = {1}", databaseName,backupFileName);
    using (cmd == new SqlCommand(query, con)) {
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    con.Close();

    con.InfoMessage -= OnInfoMessage;
    con.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = false;

    //============ Database operation end==================

}

private void OnInfoMessage(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
{

    lblStatusMsg.Text = e.Message; // mostly messages are like. 1 percent complete, 5 percent complete, 11 percent complete


    foreach (SqlError info in e.Errors) {
        if (info.Class > 10) {
                           // errror logging
        } else {
            Regex reger = new Regex("\\d+");
            Match regerMatch = reger.Match(e.Message);

            if (ProgressBar1.Value == 100) {

            } else {

                ProgressBar1.Value = regerMatch.Value;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Not responding issue until database operation completes

Comment: So you making sure `Thread.Sleep(10000)` is executed on UI thread and unhappy about it at the same time. Please decide what you want first and than update question.

Comment: Curious to know,Why did not you use backgroundworker thread and why do you want to create your own thread and why is there a sleep?

Comment: Thread.Sleep(10000) is just example. My actual code takes much time to complete the operation.I'm going to remove  Thread.Sleep(10000) from above example for avoiding confusion

Comment: So you are making sure slow operation is done on UI thread (not much difference from previous version)...

Comment: *sigh* No, _don't_ invoke everything, just the bits that need to interact with the UI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of the `Invoke` call is to have code run on the main thread.  Your code is therefore creating a thread whose entire purpose is to force the main thread to run all the code.

Let's assume that you want to run a thread that, 10 seconds after it starts, updates a label's text to indicate completion.  You still need to `Invoke` the label update, but that's the only thing that should be in the invoke.

In that case your thread function should look something like this:

```
private void MyThreadFunc()
{
    // do something here
    Thread.Sleep(10000);

    // update the label:
    if (label1.InvokeRequired)
        Invoke(UpdateLabel);
    else
        UpdateLabel();
}

private void UpdateLabel()
{
    label1.Text = "Something was finished.";
}
```

In other words, you need to separate out those things that *have* to run on the main thread (like anything that updates controls on your form) and `Invoke` only those bits.  The rest of it should happen outside of the `Invoke`.

---

I guess I didn't make it clear.

The `Invoke` method is used to execute code in the context of the thread that owns the handle of the control or form that you're invoking on.  You can use this to interact with controls on the UI, but you should *only* use it for that purpose.  If you put all of the thread's close in an `Invoke` call then all of the thread's code will run in the UI thread, which makes it completely pointless to have a separate thread.

If you want to stop your application's UI from pausing while things happen - which is, after all, one of the main reasons to use a thread - then you should use the `Invoke` method only when absolutely necessary, and then only for very small sections of code.  Call `Invoke` to update a control's parameters, interact with the non-threadsafe properties of the form, etc.  You can use dialog boxes and so on directly from your other thread, although some prefer to use `Invoke` for those as well.

And if you're doing multiple invokes then you probably should write some helper methods to wrap the `Invoke` to clean things up.  Something like:

```
public void Invoker(Action action)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
        Invoke(action);
    else
        action();
}

public T Invoker<T>(Func<T> func)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
        return (T)Invoke(func);
    else
        return func();
}
```

Now you can write your thread code with minimal impact like this:

```
public void ThreadFunc()
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Invoker(() => this.label1.Text = "Started");
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Invoker(() => this.label1.Text = string.Format("Iteration {0}", i));
    }
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Invoker(() => this.label1.Text = "Completed");
}
```

Or if you don't like lambda functions (for some reason) you can use methods like this:

```
public void Invoker<T>(Action<T> action, T p)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
        Invoke(action, p);
    else
        action(p);
}

private void SetLabel(string value)
{
    label1.Text = value;
}
```

And then in your code:

```
Invoker(SetLabel, "new text value");
```

The important part is to keep the code you're invoking be tiny or you'll end up blocking your main thread.

Comment: Code is also reading information from UI for processing.There is also dialog open there so how can I separate these things?

Comment: Each time you need to interact with the UI thread, use a separate `Invoke`.